# jQuery: find() text input without a particular attr

Tags: jquery

How can I filter text inputs and only get those without the attribute `tabindex=-1` ?
I found this code and what this does is get every input that's not hidden.

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` method:

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form')
                .find('input[type=text]')
                .not('[tabindex="-1"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:not([tabindex=-1])');
```

or

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find('input').not('[tabindex=-1]');
```

For specificity you can mention `input[type=text]`

Comment: `without the attribute tabindex=-1`

Answer (score 1):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter out elements

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible').not('[tabindex=-1]');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var inputs = $('input:not[tabindex^="-1"]')
```